# layoutMargins are not consistent across iPhone and iPad

Tags: ios12, layoutmargins

**iPad 11 inch**

```
(lldb) po UIApplication.shared.windows[0].layoutMargins
▿ UIEdgeInsets
  - top : 32.0
  - left : 8.0
  - bottom : 28.0
  - right : 8.0
```

**iPad 10.5 inch**

```
(lldb) po UIApplication.shared.windows[0].layoutMargins
▿ UIEdgeInsets
  - top : 28.0
  - left : 8.0
  - bottom : 8.0
  - right : 8.0
```

**iPhone 8 Plus**

```
(lldb) po UIApplication.shared.windows[0].layoutMargins
▿ UIEdgeInsets
  - top : 8.0
  - left : 8.0
  - bottom : 8.0
  - right : 8.0
```

It makes sense that the new iPad 11 inch model has a lager top margin than the 10.5 inch model due to the round corner. But why the top margin of the iPad 10.5 inch model is not 8.0? iPhone has consistent margins across all edges though...

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because the iPad has the status bar enabled. I get your results on the iPad 10.5 inch when the status bar is enabled, and I get all 8s when the status bar is disabled.

What I'm trying to figure out is why on the iPad 11 inch when the status bar is disabled the top margin is 8 and not 28 like the bottom.